# React parent layout depends on children (must rerender when they do)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got an accordion component I call `Collapsible`. It animates the revealing and hiding of its children. It works wonderfully if the child content is static in size, but my application can't rely on that, since some child components have their own conditional rendering of child components. I realize I could pass down a `setState` function to trigger a rerender, but I would prefer if the children could be agnostic about whether they are inside a `Collapsible` or not.

The one solution I can think of is to add an optional prop to each kind of child component for this rerender trigger, but I'd *prefer* if there were some other way I'm not seeing -- one that would allow the children to be truly agnostic about their parents.

Here is the accordion component (with TypeScript type annotations):

```
const Collapsible = ({ open, label, handleClick, children }: Props): ReactElement => {
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const contentClassName = open ? `${styles.content} ${styles.open}` : styles.content;
  const arrowClassName = open ? `${styles.arrow} ${styles.open}` : styles.arrow;

  const maxHeight = open ? contentRef.current?.scrollHeight + 'px' : '0px';

  return (
      <>
          <div className={styles.div} onClick={handleClick}>
              <span className={styles.label}>{label}</span>
              <button className={styles.button}>
                  <span className={arrowClassName}></span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div ref={contentRef} style={{ maxHeight }} className={contentClassName}>
              {children}
          </div>
      </>
  );
};
```

Comment: React components really only need to re-render when their state or props update. *Why* would a parent component need to rerender if a descendent happens to rerender? Can the containing div for `children` just be allowed to automatically grow to fit children? Almost 100% of the time if you think the solution to a react problem is to allow a child to force rerender a parent you've gone sideways on the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `max-height` to `none` rather than to a fixed px value when open, then it should expand automatically to fit the content.

```js
const maxHeight = open ? 'none' : '0px';
```

Comment: Great idea. Clearly I went down the wrong path with the way I framed my question -- it's really about css not react. Clearly I need some sleep. Thanks.